# Switching between 2 24V 30A power sources

Tags: mosfet, diodes, relay

I am trying to make a changeover switch. The current at full load which the switch needs to handle is 30A.
I looked into automotive relays, but I believe they are not rated for continuous use.
I also found out about shotcky diodes, but I believe they are not suited for my needs, here is why:

The two sources consist of:
One solar charger controller which will output battery voltage and eventually cut at 22V low voltage and 3 parallel 24V smps

If my understanding is correct, using shotcky diodes will work, but as soon as the battery bank will reach a value lower than the smps the power will be drawn from this. Also there will be some power loss, which I would like to avoid.

Instead I would like the system to be powered until the battery reaches 22V and only then it should switch to the smps. Once battery output will be again available from the controller, the system should switch back to battery.

I thought of using mosfets, but I don't want current to flow back trough the body diode to the controller or to the smps.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The recommended LTC4418 is [about $6 at Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/linear-technology-analog-devices/LTC4418CUF-PBF/LTC4418CUF-PBF-ND/7796553) - Making a PCB for it may be annoying. An alternative is to implement the back to back MOSFET pairs but use an opamp or comparator to handle the changeover. The ICs involved are smaller and have a range of options to suit construction style. || There are relays that will handle your requirement. At 30A dissipation in contacts is about 1 Watt per milliOhm so this can be significant - but suitable auto relays should be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MOSFETs, but you must gang two of them source-to-source in each power path so that the body diodes prevent current backflow down the 'inactive' path.

One such example (by no means unique) is the [LTC4418](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc4418.html#product-overview), a dual channel prioritized power-path controller. A sample application is shown below:

[image]

(Image courtesy of Analog Devices)

The voltage thresholds are set with resistors (which includes some level of hysteresis) and the chip then drives the gates of the respective power path, providing a resistance that is 2*RDSon for each path. You can also parallel MOSFETs to lower this further -- MOSFET selection is dependent on parameters such as form factor, SOA, gate charge, allowable operating temperatures, etc., so this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I had a quick look at the chip you suggested... It looks like is exactly what I need. Originally I just wanted to drive the mosfet switch via a microcontroller, just switching between te two when battery power is available or not. This looks better. Thanks.